# Fail to push static site to Bluemix using third-party buildpack

Tags: push, cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud, static-files

I just use this buildpack for my static site:

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/staticfile-buildpack.git

Got this error from the push command:

-----> Downloaded app package (1.5M)

Cloning into '/tmp/buildpacks/staticfile-buildpack'...

Submodule 'compile-extensions' (https://github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/co
mpile-extensions.git) registered for path 'compile-extensions'
Cloning into 'compile-extensions'...
Submodule path 'compile-extensions': checked out '1f260464c156bddfb654adb1429834
4797d030a1'
It looks like you're deploying on a stack that's not supported by this buildpack
.
That could be because you're using a recent buildpack release on a deprecated st
ack.
If you're using the buildpack installed by your CF admin, please let your admin
know you saw this error message.
If you at one point specified a buildpack that's at git URL, please make sure yo
u're pointed at a version that supports this stack.
Staging failed: Buildpack compilation step failed

Fail
BuildpackCompileFailed

I have use this buildpack a few weeks ago and it works.

Answer (score 2):

There are currently two types of stacks in the environment (lucid64 and cflinuxfs2). Some of the community buildpacks might not work with one or the other. The static buildpack needs cflinuxfs2. Until the default is changed to cflinixfs2, you can specify the stack with the **-s** option

```
cf push <appname> -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry/staticfile-buildpack.git -s cflinuxfs2
```